# MySQL: Exclude subsets if not all row values are true

Tags: mysql

I have three `MySQL` tables: `ingredients`, `ingredient_in_recipe` and `recipes` which can be `INNER JOIN`ed to get ingredients in recipes. Also, the `ingredients` table has a column `vegetarian`. I want to get all recipes that are considered vegetarian, meaning that *all* ingredients for a given recipe must have set `vegetarian` to 1 (it is a `BOOL`/`tinyint(1)`).

I have looked at queries using `ALL`, `HAVING NOT MAX` and other various stuff, but I cannot find a working solution. What is the best way to do this? Are there some solutions that are more efficient than others?

**Extra (only relevant) table information:**

```
mysql> DESCRIBE ingredients;
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vegetarian      | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE ingredient_in_recipe;
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| recipe_id     | int(11)                | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ingredient_id | int(11)                | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> DESCRIBE recipes;
+------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                   | text                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The start of my query is currently:

```
SELECT recipe.name, ingredient.name
    FROM ingredients AS ingredient
    INNER JOIN ingredient_in_recipe AS ir
        ON ir.ingredient_id = ingredient.id
    INNER JOIN recipes AS recipe
        ON ir.recipe_id = recipe.id;
```

So I am missing a `WHERE`, `ALL`, `IN` or something statement at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT r.name FROM recipes r WHERE r.id NOT IN (
  SELECT ir.recipe_id FROM ingredient_in_recipe ir
  INNER JOIN ingredients i ON ir.ingredient_id = i.id
  WHERE i.vegeterian = 0
)
```

Comment: from a performance standpoint i would suggest not using correlated subqueries unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. I have not used the `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` before, so this is a good solution. For a more verbose explanation, see @Bret's answer. Will there be any trouble using `= 0` instead of `<> 1` in this case? I am certain that `vegetarian` will be either 0 (false) or 1 (true).

Comment: Yes it's better to use 0

Comment: Yes, the alternative query also works. This will be slightly faster, right?

Comment: I'm not sure for the distinct. It will work without. In either case, I would create both indexes in `ingredient_in_recipe` and an index on `vegeterian`

Comment: It will work without the `DISTINCT` because the set we *exclude* may contain several instances of the same recipe ID, which is fine. The `DISTINCT` may keep things a bit clearer to the reader though and is maybe a bit more "correct".

Comment: Really .... don't use correlated subqueries if you don't have to.  It'll work fine when you have a few records in your DB.... but it won't scale.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way.

1. Select out the set of recipes that have any non-vegitarian ingredients.
2. Subtract this set from the set of all recipes.

So here's the set of all recipes with a non veg ingredient.

```
    select
      id 
    from
      recipes,
      ingredient_in_recipe,
      ingredients
    where
      ingredient_in_recipe.recipe_id = recipes.id
    and
      ingredient_in_recipe.ingredient_id = ingredients.id
    and
      ingredients.vegetarian <> 1
```

Note: why are you using a tinyint to mark a boolen?  USE Boolean to mark boolean.

Also your DB model is pretty good.  Your naming is consistent and appropriate.

Now that we have the "non-vegitarian" recipes, we just subtract from a "set" perspective [as in set theory].

```
select
  *
from
  recipes
where
  id NOT IN (
    -- this subquery returns a set of IDs corresponding to non-vegitarian recipes.
    select
      id 
    from
      recipes,
      ingredient_in_recipe,
      ingredients
    where
      ingredient_in_recipe.recipe_id = recipes.id
    and
      ingredient_in_recipe.ingredient_id = ingredients.id
    and
      ingredients.vegetarian <> 1
  );
```

Comment: When I created the table I used the `BOOL` data type, which got converted to `TINYINT(1)`. At least, I am pretty sure it did. Anyway, these two data types are considered [equivalent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html). Here, it is stated: `BOOL, BOOLEAN

These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true.`

Comment: This does not work entirely, as the table `ingredient_in_recipe` is left out of the query. This table sorts the many-to-many relationship between `ingredients` and `recipes`. The `ingredients` table does not contain the field `recipe_id`, it is in `ingredient_in_recipe`. I think the `INNER JOIN` in @JuniorCompressor's answer is required.